# Python selenium - How to store file on s3 from firefox download

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using python 3.8 + selenium package on aws lambda and firefox driver

So how can I set the download location for firefox profile in selenium?

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.downloads.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.downloads.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.downloads.dir","HOW TO SET S3 PATH HERE")
```

If not then what is the best way to implement it

Comment: firefox can only use a local directory, so either you system has to mount s3 to the file system, or be able to reach the s3 resource. More likely you want to download locally and then upload it to s3 as a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium doesn't know anything about AWS or S3. You can download files to the local filesystem, then upload to S3 with boto3. For example:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.downloads.dir", DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY)

# when Selenium run is complete, create a gzipped tar file of downloads
tarball = "{0}.tar.gz".format(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY)
with tarfile.open(tarball, "w:gz") as f:
    f.add(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY)
    client = boto3.client("s3")
    try:
        client.upload_file(tarball, S3_BUCKET, s3_key_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        log.error(e)
```

Comment: Thanks kielni really appreciate your support